# PHP SQL query error - Unknown array column in WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My page displays the name of players of a certain sports team using drop down menus. The coach can log in to pick his team and select the opposition which his team will play against.
When user has selected the team and opposition he clicks submit and the isset function is triggered.

Now I capture the values from the drop down menus and upload it to the correct table in the DB. Everything is pretty straight forward however when I click submit I get the error in the tittle. Any help would be appreciated

```
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    $player_ids = array_map('intval', $_REQUEST['players']);
    $opponents_id = $_REQUEST['players'];

    var_dump($player_ids);
    var_dump($opponents_id);

    $query = 'SELECT `name`, `position` 
        FROM `player_info` 
        WHERE `player_id` IN (' . implode(',', $player_ids) . ')';

    $return_names = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

         while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($return_names) ) 
        {
            $selected[] = $row['name'];
            $position[] = $row['position'];
        }

    $query = ("SELECT `fixture_id` 
                FROM `fixtures`     
                WHERE `fixture_id` = $opponents_id") 
                or die (mysql_error()); 

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
                {
                    $fixture_id[] = $row['fixture_id']; 

                }
                        for ($i=0; sizeof($selected) > $i; $i++){
                             $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `team` (`selection_id`, `fixture_id`, `player_position`,`player_name`) 
                                                VALUES ('$fixture_id[$i]','$position[$i]','$selected[$i]')") 
                                                or die(mysql_error());
                                echo $selected[$i]; 
                                echo $position[$i];
                                echo $fixture_id[$i];
                                echo'<br>';


}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unknown column 'Array' in WHERE clause

Comment: Which one is line 37?

Comment: show the var_dump of `implode(',', $player_ids)`

Comment: Don't you have a missing value in your insert? You want to populate 4 columns in the INSERT, but you provide only 3 values - value for SELECTION_ID is missing.

Comment: "WHERE `fixture_id` = $opponents_id". $opponents_id is an array, too.

Comment: Thank you good point but the error gets triggered before then

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_` function is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Comment: @redreggae please can you explain a bit more

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee: See *cillosis*'s answer below.

Comment: You should always encapsulate all variables from strings e.g. `"SELECT * FROM " . $table . " WHERE columnA = '" . $blargh . ';"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'** error means literally what it says -- you tried to put an array value into your where clause.

In this line:

```
$query = ("SELECT `fixture_id` 
            FROM `fixtures`     
            WHERE `fixture_id` = $opponents_id") 
            or die (mysql_error());
```

You are using the `$opponents_id` variable which your `var_dump` shows is an array containing five values. So, you need to use the IN clause and list them out (just like you did for `$player_ids`):

```
$query = ("SELECT `fixture_id` 
            FROM `fixtures`     
            WHERE `fixture_id` IN (" . implode(",", $opponents_id) . ");") 
            or die (mysql_error());
```

Note: Hopefully you are aware of the tiring subject of the `mysql_*` family of functions. These are being deprecated and are insecure. I wrote about it a while back: http://www.jorble.com/2012/06/you-are-vulnerable-for-sql-injection/

Comment: No worries. Good luck on your project.

Comment: can you please have a quick look at the code for your solution. There is a syntax error. I cant spot it...

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the right parenthesis wrapped around the query string. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

bodi0 is right, your **$opponents_id** is an array , if it must be an array so do some things like that

```
$opponents_id_text=implode(',',$opponents_id);
$query = ("SELECT `fixture_id` 
                FROM `fixtures`     
                WHERE `fixture_id` in ($opponents_id_text)") 
                or die (mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your second SQL query:

```
WHERE `fixture_id` = $opponents_id" -
```

Here the `$opponents_id` is array (it is converted automatically to array when you assign the value to it from the `$_REQUEST`, because the HTML component `select` sends the options as array). 
Just `implode()` it also, like you did for `$player_ids`.

Answer (score -1):

you did not specified Array properly in sql query.

when we use Arrays we have to specify array number in query

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to specify it properly?